# Intersection of Sets and Graph

Tags: combinatorics

Consider nonempty sets $S_1, S_2, \dots, S_k$ that contain positive integers between 1 and $t$ inclusive such that each positive integer in the range appears at least one.

Any pair of sets $S_i, S_j$ satisfy $|S_i \cap S_j | \in \{0,2\}$.

For any two distinct positive integers, the number of sets they both appear in is either 0 or 2.

If you build a graph with nodes $1$ through $t$ inclusive and edges between any two numbers that appear in the same set, the graph is connected.

Prove the size of each set is the same, let this be $m$. Then each positive integer in the range $1$ through $t$ appears $m$ times.
Find the maximum number of sets given a fixed $m$.

I tried to prove this via contradiction, but it didn't work. Specifically, consider two sets that intersect. Is it going to help to remove the two intersecting elements and use induction? The only issue, I'm not sure how to manage the graph and the rest of the intersections and that stuff.

Otherwise, I was trying to use double counting trying to do this. but idk how to continue.

Comment: Yes, good catch @bof

Comment: Well, any proof that doesn't use the distinctness of $S_i$ is wrong, because one can have the system: $S_1 = \{1,2,3\}, S_2 = \{1, 2,4\}, S_3 = \{1,3,4\}, S_4 = \{2,3,4\}, S_5 = S_6 = \{5,6\}$. In fact, if $m$ is the same for each $S_i$, then something stronger must be true: that all such systems of $S_1, \dots, S_k$ share the same $m$. This makes me think that $m=3$ is the only solution, with disjoint copies of $S_1, \dots, S_4$ described above (for $t = 4l$ for some $l$) being the only configuration.

Comment: If $x\in S_i$ then $|S_i|=|\{j:x\in S_j\}|$. To see this, define a bijection between $S_i\setminus\{x\}$ and $\{j:x\in S_j\}\setminus\{i\}$.

Comment: @koifish In your example the graph is not connected.

Comment: @koifish The question stipulates that "the graph is connected".

Comment: @freeloader_21 If $x\in S_i$ you can define a bijection $f:\{j:x\in S_j\}\setminus\{i\}\to S_i\setminus\{x\}$ so that $S_i\cap S_j=\{x,f(j)\}$. Once you have established that $x\in S_i\implies|\{j:x\in S_j\}|=|S_i|$, use connectedness to show that there is a number $m$ such that $|S_i|=|\{j:x\in S_j\}|=m$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ and all $x\in\{1,\dots,t\}$.